# Cuboid equation notation

Tags: analysis, compactness

Have seen such an equation for a cuboid in $(\mathbb{R}^n, ||\cdot||_{\infty})$:

$\displaystyle Q=\prod_{i=1}^{n} [a_ib_i]$, where $a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{R}, a_i \le b_i$.

How does it describe a cuboid? Is that really a product of some $[a_1,b_1], [a_2, b_2], \ldots$? Then how it forms a 3D, 4D or nD thing? If not, how the notation should be read?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The notation for a product of to sets is $A\times B=\{(x,y)\mid x\in A,y\in B\}$

$\displaystyle Q=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n[a_i,b_i]=[a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2]\times ...\times[a_n,b_n]$

And it means $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in Q\iff \forall\ 1\le i\le n\ :\ x_i\in[a_i,b_i]$

So for $n=1$ this is a segment.

For $n=2$ this is a rectangle.

For $n=3$ this is a brick or rectangular parallelepiped.

For any $n$, the general term is cuboid, for that if $\forall i\ :\ a_i=0$ and $b_i=1$ then $Q=[0,1]^n$ is the hypercube of dimension $n$.